# Why run-time differs in an array search scenario C#

Tags: c#, performance-testing, performancecounter

I'm currently testing the average time of a numeric search within an array. I'm testing against a binary search, a sequential index search, and a custom function. The array is initialized with a random length and random values. I noticed two things when testing...

1.) In the program loop below my custom function is approx 5-7 times faster than a binary search, depending on array size. Usually it is a lot faster when the array is larger which was the goal.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] randomarray = CreateRandomArray();
    for(int loops = 0;loops < totalsamples;loops ++)
    {
        int tosearchfor = CreateRandomNumber();
        RecordMyCustomFunctionTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
        RecordBinarySearchTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
        RecordSequentialSearchTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
    }
    CalculateAndDisplayAverages();
}
```

2.) In the program loop below my custom function is approx 2-3 times faster depending on array size. Binary Search and Sequential Search are roughly the same as before

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for(int loops = 0;loops < totalsamples;loops ++)
    {
        int[] randomarray = CreateRandomArray();
        int tosearchfor = CreateRandomNumber();
        RecordMyCustomFunctionTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
        RecordBinarySearchTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
        RecordSequentialSearchTime(randomarray,tosearchfor);
    }
    CalculateAndDisplayAverages();
}
```

I've also tested this with a set array size and the same results. I'm using the Stopwatch class and it reports I have a high resolution performance counter. Why such a difference depending just on where the array is created and just for my function?

Comment: Memory allocation is a heavy task that takes time.

Comment: @Idov it's not within the the start of the test time to the end of the test time, the time elasped is measured on each function call and return. I'm a 100% sure it's not being calculated in.

Comment: You'll have to show us more code...